# Confused by this PHP Exception try..catch nesting

Tags: php, exception

I'm confused by the following code:

```
class MyException extends Exception {}
class AnotherException extends MyException {}

class Foo {
  public function something() {
    print "throwing AnotherException\n";
    throw new AnotherException();
  }
  public function somethingElse() {
    print "throwing MyException\n";
    throw new MyException();
  }
}

$a = new Foo();

try {
  try {
    $a->something();    

  } catch(AnotherException $e) {
    print "caught AnotherException\n";
    $a->somethingElse();    
  } catch(MyException $e) {
    print "caught MyException\n";
  }
} catch(Exception $e) {
  print "caught Exception\n";
}
```

I would expect this to output:

```
throwing AnotherException
caught AnotherException
throwing MyException
caught MyException
```

But instead it outputs:

```
throwing AnotherException
caught AnotherException
throwing MyException
caught Exception
```

Could anyone explain why it "skips over" catch(MyException $e) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The exception handlers catch exception raised by code inside the scope of their try block.

The call to `$a->somethingElse()` does NOT occur within the try block associated with the skipped exception handler. It occurs within another catch clause.

Just because it appears physically below the line that raises the exception isn't enough to make it cover that code.

The style choice of indenting braces makes this less clear, IMHO. The close brace for the previous try block appears on the same line as the next catch, even though they are unrelated (well, sibling) scopes.

Comment: I just want to be sure we're on the same page... Basically he should have added another `try` after the first `catch`, right? Then, because the entire thing is embedded in the larger try, he would get 3 sets of exceptions? Essentially it never catches the second exception because it never tries?

Comment: If he had, alternatively, changed the outer `catch` to "MyException" instead of "Exception" would this have caught the "MyException" `throw`? Is the issue that his attempt triggers the `throw` of "MyException" but because the attempt wasn't initiated by a `try`, the `catch` never happens? In other words, is "MyException" still out there to be caught by that third `catch`?

Comment: @Anthony, re: First comment: Yes, if he added a third level of try block that would be one solution. Bit messy though. I wouldn't choose to characterise the problem as you have in your last sentence, but it isn't *wrong*.

Comment: @Anthony, re: 2nd comment, 1st question: Yes, if he changed the outer catch as your describe, it would catch the exception, but the outer catch is ALREADY catching the exception! It is catching it as a *Exception* rather than as a *MyException*, but it is the same exception!

Answer (score 7):

Only because there isn't enough room for this in a comment.  Think of the try...catch as an if...else loop.  You wouldn't expect the following:

```
$a = 10;
if($a == 9)
    print "\$a == 9";
elseif($a == 10) {
    $a = 11;
    echo "now \$a == 11";
} elseif($a == 11) {
    echo "\$a == 11";
}
```

to print out the last condition ("\$a == 11"), because the condition was already met by the first `elseif`.  The same is true with the try...catch.  If the condition is met, it doesn't continue searching for new conditions in the same scope.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if following is legal ("try"ing inside a catch block), but does give expected output:

```
class MyException extends Exception {}
class AnotherException extends MyException {}

class Foo {
  public function something() {
    print "throwing AnotherException\n";
    throw new AnotherException();
  }
  public function somethingElse() {
    print "throwing MyException\n";
    throw new MyException();
  }
}

$a = new Foo();

try {
   try {
      $a->something();
   } catch(AnotherException $e) {
       print "caught AnotherException\n";
       try{
          $a->somethingElse();
       } catch(MyException $e) {
          print "caught MyException\n";
       }
   }
} catch(Exception $e) {
  print "caught Exception\n";
}
```

Gives output:

```
throwing AnotherException
caught AnotherException
throwing MyException
caught MyException
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been considered answered or not, but the answer is even simpler than what has been posed here. For every try, only ONE catch block can be triggered and it will always be the most specific one applicable.

In this case, AnotherException is thrown and handled by the first catch block of the inner try/catch, so it won't be handled by the second catch block. The new exception thrown in the catch block get's handled by the outer try/catch.